# Allow Timthumb to work in a htpasswd protected Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, .htpasswd, timthumb

I have a domain I use for development purposes. In this domain I have several subdirectories with different wordpress installations.
To hide the whole area I made a simple htpasswd protection in the root.

Now I have one of this Wordpress in the domain that uses timthumb library to resize images, and due to the htpasswd, I get "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request" instead of the image.

This is an example of the request that gets the error

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/WP/wp-content/plugins/plugin-directory/timthumb.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fsubdomain.domain.com%2FWP%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F01%2F012015_valentines_hp_budvase.jpg&w=300&h=620&zc=1
```

Is there a way to bypass the protection only for that file?

More details on my paths to better read my .htaccess snippets:

- I'm in a subdomain pointed to a subdirectory called 'subdomain_folder'
- .htaccess I'm working on is located in 'subdomain_folder'
- WP is in a subdirectory called 'WP' inside 'subdomain_folder'
- Complete Path to WP: '/home/some-folder/public_html/subdomain_folder/WP
- Complete Path to Uploads: '/home/some-folder/public_html/subdomain_folder/WP/wp-content/uploads

I tried this:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/WP/wp-content/plugins/plugin-dir/timthumb\.php$" allow
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile "/home/some-folder/.htpasswds/public_html/subdomain_folder/passwd"
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=allow
Satisfy any
```

**UPDATE**

Someone adviced me that allowing access to timthumb.php file it's pointless, instead I should allow him to make http requests, or allow full access to uploads folders so, I tried the following, allowing requests from localhost ip

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Reserverd Area"
AuthUserFile "/home/some-folder/.htpasswds/public_html/subdomain_folder/passwd"
Require valid-user
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Satisfy Any
```

Tried both localhost and 127.0.0.1

I even tried to add another .htaccess in the single WP upload folder (where timthumb asks for images) with rule to allow from any

```
Satisfy Any
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
```

Still I cant' get images shown, and I keep getting the NetworkError: 400 Bad Request" instead of the image.

Last Detail, the .htaccess in the WP directory is a standard wp htaccess --> pastebin.com/8PRqEYQ2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the solution.

The right way is indeed allowing requests from the server itself, but the localhost IP (127.0.0.1) was not the right adress to allow.
I made a Reverse IP Lookup searching for the domain I'm on, and I used that IP.

This is the .htaccess that works

```
RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile "/home/path-to-passfile/passwd"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
# Use your server ip:
Allow from 111.111.111.11
Satisfy Any
</IfModule>
```

With this rules I can develop apps using timthumb.php in .htpasswd protected directory.

Criticisms and improvements are welcome :)